# Record as Response Getting Empty

Tags: c#, response, record

I have Response Dto as record type like below:

```
public record CustomerItsDetailDto
    { 
        public string VirtualVisitStatus;
        public List<CustomerItsTaskDetailDto> TaskDetails;
    }
```

[image]

When I debug it I can see the response is not empty. But I am getting empty response in the postman. What is the problem here?

Controller part;

Controller seems like this;

```
[HttpGet]
    [Route("its/customerdetail")]
    public async Task<CustomerItsDetailDto> GetItsCustomerDetailInPmaktif(string customerCode) => await posRepository.GetItsCustomerDetail(customerCode);
```

I know that if I change record the class i can get the response. But why record is not working?

Comment: You have only shown us a partial method here, what is that method entirely? Is it an action method? There's nothing we can do to help with such little information.

Comment: The important part is the controller method, not the record.

Comment: my wild guess would be that you are returning json and your record properties have no setter.

Comment: Added the controller part

Comment: Also, why are you using a `record` but giving it fields instead of properties? Your record should be written as `public record CustomerItsDetailDto(string VirtualVisitStatus, List<CustomerItsTaskDetailDto> TaskDetails);` This could explain why you get empty response since fields are not serialised.

Comment: Yes actually record makes their props {get; init;} as default. But like i said i can see the response on the return value. Why my controller not getting it?

Comment: @ferhattumer it's beacuse you are not having props but fields in your record. By declaring fields you are not using the default .

Comment: Thanks!!  jeb&DavidG This is the problem. Using the default solved. Getting correct values when debugging made me confuse.

Comment: @ferhattumer if the question is answered please mark it as answered (green) so others know about in the future.

Comment: @jeb begging for answers/votes is really frowned upon here, and thanks for taking my comment and making it an answer...

Comment: @DavidG that's not my point. I was lectured that answering in comment's is not what the platform suggest. Also if the question has valid answers is important information for future visitors.

Comment: @DavidG if want to provide your own answer i would love to give you a vote if it's a good answer.

Comment: @DavidG i noted you in the answer hope thats better now.

Comment: @ferhattumer Small comment about the code: assigning `taskDetails ?? null` is pointless. Since the right-hand side of `??` will only be used if the left hand side is `null`, `taskDetails ?? null` essentially says "Use `taskDetails`, unless it is `null`, then use `null`." which is the same as just using `taskDetails`.

Comment: Thanks @LWChris I was trying to do something. I forgot it there. It's not in the code right now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are declaring fields instead of properties.

```
public record CustomerItsDetailDto
{ 
    public string VirtualVisitStatus;
    public List<CustomerItsTaskDetailDto> TaskDetails;
}
```

Credits to DavidG for his excellent comment (see above).
You should declare your record as follows:

```
public record CustomerItsDetailDto(string VirtualVisitStatus, List<CustomerItsTaskDetailDto> TaskDetails);
```

this will create  `{get; init;}` properties.

Or you can create the properties yourself.

```
public record CustomerItsDetailDto
{ 
    public string VirtualVisitStatus {get; init;}
    public List<CustomerItsTaskDetailDto> TaskDetails {get; init;} = new()
}
```